# Removing Page Extensions using DD4T

Tags: 2013-sp1, dd4t, java

We are using DD4T Java for one of our website build using Tridion 2013 SP1.

One of the requirements says we should not display page extensions.

Current page urls  : www.mysite.com/newsroom/newsarticles/mybank.html

expected page urls : www.mysite.com/newsroom/newsarticles/mybank

How this can be done using DD4T Java?

Comment: I don't actually know how it can be done for DD4T, but we do it in the DXA (which uses DD4T underneath). Maybe someone can expand on this.

Answer (score 2):

Would this solve your issue ? - http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

Answer (score 2):

URL Rewrite is the way to go. We did it successfully in .NET. Should be possible in Java too.
A quick google gave many options "url rewrite to remove extension in java"

Comment: It is - Tuckey is a good rewriter.

Answer (score 1):

We normally put each page in a separate structure group with filename as index.html, with this you don't need to provide index.html in the URL and still the page can be accessed. Not an ideal solution though but works.

Answer (score 1):

As Nuno mentions, DXA supports this as well.
The solution is similar to the answer suggesting to change the GetContentByUrl() method.

While that solution will work, it's not ideal, as we don't want to modify core DD4T files.

I'm not sure if you use DD4T v1 or v2 for java, the below code samples are based on v2 (but a similar approach will work for v1 as well)

A better solution is to override the functionality of the DynamicPageController (https://github.com/dd4t/dd4t-2-java/blob/develop/dd4t-example-site/src/main/java/org/dd4t/springmvc/controller/DynamicPageController.java)

In line 121, you find this piece of code

```
Page pageModel = (Page) genericPageFactory.findPageByUrl(URL, publication);
```

You should alter this logic, and check for different variations of the URL variable (this variable contains the url you put in your browser.

- First check if you can find the original URL (e.g http://www.mysite.com/news)
- If this can't be found, add and index page (in case you are requesting a directory, so change URL variable to "http://www.mysite.com/news/index.html", and call the function again
- if you still don't get a result, then change URL variable to "http://www.mysite.com/news.html" (the extension might vary depending on what you defined in your page templates)

One caveat for dd4t java version 2 is that it's better to check if a page exists by calling the method

```
genericPageFactory.isPagePublished(URL, publication).
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

in **"DD4T.providers.SDLTridion2013sp1"** solution

you will find **"GetContentByUrl(string Url)"** append ".html" to this url string

**url = url+".html";**

this works for .NET, u can try the same for JAVA also.

please do let me know if this works.

Comment: Should any code in here actually be changed? You'd be changing the source for DD4T core, won't that affect your ability to upgrade later?

Comment: this wont affect anything. after upgrade if u still need this functionality make sure u make changes to the new source code of DD4T.

Comment: Can't argue with that logic Nuno ;)

Comment: We are asking for removal of extension instead of adding please let me know your thoughts on this